# Can't catch meteor error thrown in Method from Event

Tags: meteor

I have a method and it throws an error so I can catch it in my event and display it to the user, like this:

```
  Meteor.methods({
    addPlayer: function(nickname) {
      if (nickname == "") {
        throw new Meteor.Error('empty-nickname', 'You must choose a nickname');
      } else {
        Player.insert({
          nickname: nickname,
        });
      }
    },
  })
```

and in my event

```
'submit form': function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var nickname = $('input').val();

  Meteor.call('addPlayer', nickname, function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(typeof error);
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}
```

However, meteor still throws an Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'addPlayer', and the error variable is not an error object, but a string with the same message as the console log, so I get two errors in my console instead of an error object.

Wrapping method.call in a try/catch does not work.

What am I missing here?

-- Edit
Here is an print screen of the result:
[image: Console print screen]

Image link for full resolution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zABar.png

Comment: the code seems right to me. what do you mean by "simulating the effect of invoking 'addPlayer'"? are you calling it somehow differently from what you show in the code?

Comment: where are you defining the method? on both the server and the client (stub) or just the server? ("If a stub throws an exception it will be logged to the console.")

Comment: throw new Meteor.Error(..) looks wrong. It should contain an error number.

Comment: Throwing an error did not help. The method is being defined both for server and client, and being called by the client on the event of the form submit.

Comment: Throw the error only on the server. Wrap it inside `if(!this.isSimulation) {}`

Answer (score 1):

Throw the error only on the server. Wrap it inside `if(!this.isSimulation) {}`

```
Meteor.methods({
  addPlayer: function(nickname) {
    if (nickname == "") {
      if(!this.isSimulation) {
        throw new Meteor.Error('empty-nickname', 'You must choose a nickname');
      }
    } else {
      Player.insert({
        nickname: nickname,
      });
    }
  },
})
```